# How to authorize nginx requests for MiniO?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a remote server with MiniO deployed. How can I do to get the image, not the login page, at the url http://my.site.com/images/test.jpg?

It is necessary that with the help of mod_zip to pack these files into the archive